# Filtering out Javascript injection

Tags: javascript, security, javascript-injection, html-injections

I have a textarea in which I have put validation code not to allow `<script>` tags and Javascript tags, but the user can enter descriptions like `<strong onmouseover=alert(2)>`.

So when someone hovers over this string tag JS alert box shows up.

How can I stop this kind of javascript injection?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to properly sanitize the HTML you allow. This is non-trivial, as you've discovered. (You probably need to disallow `iframe` and several other elements.)

Proper sanitizing requires a whitelist of elements, and within those a whitelist of attributes allowed on each. Obviously the various `onXyz` attributes would not be on the whitelist.

Sanitizing **must** happen server-side, because anything client-side can be bypassed. So without knowing what server technology you're using, one can't recommend something. For instance, [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) is a well-known one for Java, but of course, that's not useful to you if you aren't using Java. :-) For .Net, there's the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) or the [Microsoft Anti-XSS library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814), but this is a **very** incomplete list.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of tools called html purifiers. You can try [this](http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php) for example.

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer is `replace(/</g,'&lt;');`, but of course that prevents ***any*** HTML from being used. This is why BBCode, Markdown and other such languages exist: to provide formatting features without granting the user permission to post arbitrary code.

Alternatively, just search for things of the pattern `/\bon[a-z]+=/i`